# How to build a histogram that reads a file from Scanner?

Tags: java, file, java-io

I'm trying to build a histogram that reads a set of about 200 hundreds of numbers stored in a .txt file after I submit its name via Scanner. After that I would like to print one asterisk for each value entered.

Here it is the file:
https://gofile.io/?c=4kfTrW

I found out that in order to read files in a program I need to use java.io.
Now I saw a the documentation and I was told to import FileNotFoundException which I did not really get the reason of why.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Class83 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        int[] data = new int[200];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter file's filepath: ");

        /*reading filename*/
        String fileName = sc.nextLine();
        int index = 0;

        /*Reading file*/
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        try {
            /*Going through each element*/
            while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
                if (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
                    /*Storing numbers read from text into array*/
                    data[index] = inputFile.nextInt();
                    index++;
                } else {
                    inputFile.next();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            /*Closing file*/
            inputFile.close();
        }

        String[] Stars = {" 1-10 |", "11- 20 | ", "21- 30 | ", "31- 40 | ", "41- 50 | ",
            "51- 60 | ", "61- 70 | ", "71- 80 | ", "81- 90 | ", "91-100 | "};

        /*Going through array values*/
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            int num = data[i];
            if (num < 11) {
                Stars[0] += "*";
            } else if (num < 21) {
                Stars[1] += "*";
            } else if (num < 31) {
                Stars[2] += "*";
            } else if (num < 41) {
                Stars[3] += "*";
            } else if (num < 51) {
                Stars[4] += "*";
            } else if (num < 61) {
                Stars[5] += "*";
            } else if (num < 71) {
                Stars[6] += "*";
            } else if (num < 81) {
                Stars[7] += "*";
            } else if (num < 91) {
                Stars[8] += "*";
            } else {
                Stars[9] += "*";
            }
        }

        /*Finally printing the results*/
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(Stars[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result should be something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8g0v.jpg
but it actually trows me an error of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Random_Int.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
    at Class83.main(Class83.java:27)
C:\Users\KevinUriel\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 32 seconds)
```

Yes, I know it says it did not find the file but it is in the same folder which is why is giving me a headache. I already tried by using its filepath name and still did not work.

**UPDATE:**

It currently prints the mentioned error when I just type its name, let's say, Random_Int.txt; when I put its whole filepath, it just prints the following:

```
 1-10 |
11- 20 | 
21- 30 | 
31- 40 | 
41- 50 | 
51- 60 | 
61- 70 | 
71- 80 | 
81- 90 | 
91-100 |
```

It does not even print the stars :/

Comment: After you create the file here: `File file = new File(fileName);` could you add the following line: `System.out.println( file.getAbsolutePath() );`  Also please copy paste a directory listing of the directory where the file is at.

Comment: I did as you suggested and the path it prints is the following one: `C:\Users\KevinUriel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Test\Random_Int.txt`

Comment: That's how I have tried to pasted it as well but it just keeps trowing the same error that I mentioned in my Question....even when I type the path witout having to put only its name, it still does not print the asterisks